# How to substring characters in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Need your help guys! I don't know how to use substring yet.
For example I have data like this

```
+-----------+
+   Model   +  
+-----------+              +-----------+
|Pal5c32gld |   OUTPUT>>>  |  Pal5c    |
|Pal5s64slv |              |  Pal5s    |
|Pal5sp32gry|              |  Pal5sp   |
|Pal6e16slv |              |  Pal6e    |
|PALs32ilver|              |  Pals     |
|PalSE64gold|              |  PalSE    |
 ___________               _____________
```

TIA!

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to use it yet?  Have you tried anything?  Have you read the docs? Besides, this looks like you can just use `LEFT()` anyway....

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Look closely, it's more complicated than just using `LEFT`.

Comment: Like left(model,4) ? It seems I cant get Pal5sp32gry >>>> Pal5sp

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah your right it cant get what I want if I use only left()

Comment: Please see [ask] and then come back and [edit] your question to more clearly state your problem, explain the inconsistent output you're trying to get, and include information on the efforts you've made to solve this yourself before posting (including any searches you've made here). Thanks.

Comment: You should update your question and add a probem statement along with what you have already tried.

Comment: explain your output.

Comment: is 32,64,16 fixed number in Pal5c32gld,Pal5sp32gry?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want all characters before the first number after 'pal_'.  So:

```
select left(col, patindex('%[0-9]%', substring(col, 5, 1000)) + 4)
```

If some values don't have a number, you can do:

```
select left(col, patindex('%[0-9]%', substring(col, 5, 1000) + '0') + 4)
```

Comment: it cant get the output of 'Pal5sp'

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen . . . Why not?

Answer (score 2):

```
select  left(col, patindex('%[0-9]%', substring(col, 5, 1000)) + 3) from t
```

Comment: This answer makes me get what output I want! Thanks a  lot!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW and for fun, tested on all the examples and works. One shown below

```
DECLARE
   @string VARCHAR(500) = 'Pal5';

SELECT
   CASE
       WHEN @string LIKE '%16%'
       THEN LEFT(@string,PATINDEX('%16%',@string)-1)
       WHEN @string LIKE '%32%'
       THEN LEFT(@string,PATINDEX('%32%',@string)-1)
       WHEN @string LIKE '%64%'
       THEN LEFT(@string,PATINDEX('%64%',@string)-1)
       WHEN @string NOT LIKE '%64%'
            AND @string NOT LIKE '%32%'
            AND @string NOT LIKE '%16%'
       THEN @string
   END;
```

Comment: How about if there is no numbers 16,32,64?

Comment: @JackyMontevirgen What should the output be in that case? Or should I guess?

Comment: Quick I'm about to go to Friday night drinks :D

Comment: Sorry for the sample. Let say that I have a Model of 'HP g5' I only want to get the 'HP' but the sampl 'HP' has not only 2 chars in my other model

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)
SET @str = 'Pal5c32gld '

SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,0, patindex('%[16,32,64,128]%',@str))
```